# PHPBB language packs not appearing under ACP -> SYSTEM after install

Tags: language, phpbb

I'm new to PHPBB, I have followed the following link to install new language packs,
https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.0/kb/article/how-to-install-a-language-pack/

But I can't see the language packs menu uner ACP -> SYSTEM

[image]

What did I miss?